# How to automatically make space into a local Pouch database when reaching the storage limit?

Tags: javascript, storage, pouchdb

I'm currently developping a webapp that stocks items into a local database (with PouchDB) for offline use.

In some browsers, the storage limit is a percentage of the device available space (Chrome, Firefox), in some others the limit is fixed.

That leads me to my question:

**What strategy should I use to know when the storage limit is being reached in order to make some space into the database to save new data?**

By making space, I mean that I plan to remove a certain amount of identified old data.

My current code looks something like that:

```js
const productDB = new PouchDB('products', { auto_compaction: true });


// save items in database
const savePdtsinLocalDb = (products = []) => {
  const pdts = products.map((pdt) => ({
    _id: pdt.reference,
    ...pdt,
  }));
  productDB.bulkDocs(pdts);
};

// get item from database
const getPdtFromLocalDb = ref => productDB.get(ref);
```

Comment: You have asked a large number of questions, making this a bit broad. Please start with a search on SO such as [this one](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+pouchdb+storage+limit&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+pouchdb+storage+limit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5675j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for similar questions, then ask about specific questions that remain.

Comment: While this is indeed a well written question, it is a bit too broad and likely a duplicate of existing questions.

Comment: hi, I understand that this question can be a bit broad, but I did search on SO and PouchDB site/github without founding anything about how being notified when the storage limit is being reached. I will hovever try to simplify this question.